# Hide a div tag in PHP code

Tags: php

I want to hide a div tag in php code, where i am using HTML code inside init, if one condition is false, that particular div should not be shown. Here is my code, in this code, i want to hide `div` `id="work_exp"`

```
<?php
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$obj=$_POST['obj'];
$xdate=$_POST['xdate'];
$xmonth=$_POST['xmonth'];
$xyear=$_POST['xyear'];
$addr=$_POST['addr'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$mob=$_POST['mob'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$ms=$_POST['ms'];
$institute1=$_POST['institute1'];
$qual1=$_POST['qual1'];
$grade1=$_POST['grade1'];
$year1=$_POST['year1'];

$institute2=$_POST['institute2'];
$qual2=$_POST['qual2'];
$grade2=$_POST['grade2'];
$year2=$_POST['year2'];

$institute3=$_POST['institute3'];
$qual3=$_POST['qual3'];
$grade3=$_POST['grade3'];
$year3=$_POST['year3'];

$institute4=$_POST['institute4'];
$qual4=$_POST['qual4'];
$grade4=$_POST['grade4'];
$year4=$_POST['year4'];

$title=$_POST['title'];
$tech=$_POST['tech'];
$domain=$_POST['domain'];
$desc=$_POST['desc'];

$cert=$_POST['cert'];
$intern=$_POST['intern'];

$otrp=$_POST['otrp'];
$csk=$_POST['csk'];
$rwork=$_POST['rwork'];
$salary=$_POST['salary'];

$refname=$_POST['refname'];
$refjob=$_POST['refjob'];
$refadd=$_POST['refadd'];
$refphone=$_POST['refphone'];
$refemail=$_POST['refemail'];
$reflen=$_POST['reflen'];

session_start();

$_SESSION['ename1']=$_POST['ename1'];

$_SESSION['industry1']=$_POST['industry1'];
$_SESSION['position1']=$_POST['position1'];
$_SESSION['responsibility1']=$_POST['responsibility1'];
$_SESSION['from1']=$_POST['from1'];
$_SESSION['to1']=$_POST['to1'];
$_SESSION['ex1']=$_POST['ex1'];

$_SESSION['ename2']=$_POST['ename2'];
$_SESSION['industry2']=$_POST['industry2'];
$_SESSION['position2']=$_POST['position2'];
$_SESSION['responsibility2']=$_POST['responsibility2'];
$_SESSION['from2']=$_POST['from2'];
$_SESSION['to2']=$_POST['to2'];
$_SESSION['ex2']=$_POST['ex2'];


echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";

echo "<title>RESUME</title>";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='res.css'>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<center><font size='+3' color='#000000' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>RESUME</font></center><br /><br />";
echo "<div id='container'>";
echo "<div id='pers_detail'>";
echo "<h3>".$fname."</h3>";
echo "<h4>ADDRESS</h4>";
echo "<p>".$addr."<br />";
echo $city." - ".$pin."<br />";
echo $country."<br />";
echo "</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "<div id='con'>";
echo "<h4>CONTACT</h4>";
echo "<p>";
echo "Mobile:".$mob."<br />";
echo "E-Mail:".$email."<br />";
echo "</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='obj'>";
echo "<table width='56%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='2' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='4' align='left'><font style='background-color:#F3F5EF' size='+1' color='#000000' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OBJECTIVE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><p align='justify'>".$obj."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table></div>";
echo "<div id='academy'>";
echo "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='2' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='4' align='left'><font style='background-color:#F3F5EF' size='+1' color='#000000' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   ACADEMIC DETAILS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><p align='center'><b>INSTITUTION</b></p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'><b>QUALIFICATION</b></p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'><b>CGPA/GRADE</b></p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'><b>YEAR</b></p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
if(!$institute1=="" || $institute1!=="NIL")
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$institute1."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$qual1."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$grade1."</p></td>";
echo  "<td><p align='center'>".$year1."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
}
if(!$institute2==""|| $institute2!=="NIL")
{
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$institute2."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$qual2."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$grade2."</p></td>";
echo  "<td><p align='center'>".$year2."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
if(!$institute3==""|| $institute3!=="NIL")
{
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$institute3."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$qual3."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$grade3."</p></td>";
echo  "<td><p align='center'>".$year3."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
if(!$institute4==""|| $institute4!=="NIL")
{
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$institute4."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$qual4."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p align='center'>".$grade4."</p></td>";
echo  "<td><p align='center'>".$year4."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='aca_det'>";
echo "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='2' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='4' align='left'><font style='background-color:#F3F5EF' size='+1' color='#000000' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ACADEMIC PROJECT DETAILS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width><b>TITLE</b></td><td>".$title."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width><b>TECHNOLOGY USED</b></td><td>".$tech."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=30%><b>DOMAIN</b></td><td>".$domain."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width><b>DESCRIPTION</b></td><td><p align='justify'>".$desc."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
if($cert !="NIL" || $intern !="NIL")
{
echo "<div id='otherinfo'>";
echo "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='2' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='4' align='left'><font style='background-color:#F3F5EF' size='+1' color='#000000' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OTHER INFORMATIONS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";
if($cert !="NIL")
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width><b>CERTIFICATION</b></td><td>".$cert."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
}
if($intern !="NIL")
{
echo "<td width=30%><b>INTERNSHIP</b></td>";
echo "<td><p align='justify'>".$intern."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
}
if($_SESSION['ename1']!="" && $_SESSION['ename2']!="")
{
$new='<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#work_exp").slideDown("slow");

});
</script>
 <div id="work_exp">

 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

 <tr>
 <td colspan="4"align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WORK EXPERIANCE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 <table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4" align="left"><font size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;EMPLOYER ONE DETAILS</font></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td width="210"><b>Employer</b></td> <td width="327"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><b>Industry</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Position</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><b>Responsibilities</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><b>From</b></td><td></td>

 <td width="18"><b>To</b></td><td width="249"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><b>Salary</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 <table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4" align="left"><font size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;EMPLOYER TWO DETAILS</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="210"><b>Employer</b></td> <td width="327"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Industry</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Position</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Responsibilities</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>  
 <tr>
 <td><b>From</b></td><td></td>
 <td width="28"><b>To</b></td><td width="249"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Salary</b></td><td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>';
}
echo $new;
echo "<div id='misc'>";
echo "<table width='99%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='2' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='4' align='left'><font style='background-color:#F3F5EF' size='+1' color='#000000' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MISCELLANEOUS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='25%'><b>FULL NAME</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$fname."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='25%'><b>DATE OF BIRTH</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$xdate."/".$xmonth."/".$xyear."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>GENDER</b></td><td>".$gender."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>MARITAL STATUS</b></td><td width='75%'>".$ms."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>OWN TRANSPORT:</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$otrp."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>COMMUNICATION SKILLS:</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$csk."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>EXPECTED SALARY:</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$salary."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>READY TO WORK:</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$rwork."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='ref'>";
echo "<table width='99%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='2' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='4' align='left'><font style='background-color:#F3F5EF' size='+1' color='#000000' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;REFERENCES&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>NAME</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$refname."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>OCCUPATION</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$refjob."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>ADDRESS</b></td>";
echo "<td><p align='justify'>".$refadd."</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>CONTACT NUMBER</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$refphone."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>E-MAIL</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$refemail."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>RELATIONSHIP</b></td>";
echo "<td>".$reflen."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: this is tooooooooo much code.

Comment: You really need to format your code otherwise people will find it very hard to help you.

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "hide" - don't output the HTML, style it in CSS so it's invisible, remove the contents of the `<div>` etc. etc.?

Comment: use CSS. display: none; will do your stuff

Comment: PHP has no concept of the HTML page other than as a string of characters it sends to the client.  You could add a `style="display:none;"` or a class you can use to style the element as invisible but the logic for deciding when to do so and where to put it in your code is up to you.  Also your code is wide open to abuse.

Comment: Please post only relevant code.

Comment: you have about 100 rows of assigning variables -- I can guarantee that noone here is interested. Show only the code that you have a problem with!

Comment: dont use NIL, use NULL or just !

Answer (score 5):

First of all you shouldn't echo so much of HTML using PHP, it should be like this

```
<?php
   //Write your PHP here
?>
HTML HERE
<?php
   //PHP here again
?>
```

And about the condition, you can simply write it like this

```
<?php
  if(condition) {
?>
   Content to be shown
<?php
  }
?>
```

On the other hand you can also use `else` statement to show content if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Alien. But I need to hide the div 'work_exp', if I hide that div, next div should come that place automatically, but HTML leaving it as a blank space. I should not get like that, please help me.

Comment: @BHARATHYPARTHASARATHY You want to hide but you want that div to be physically present?

Comment: If I hide the div 'work_exp' next div must come there automatically? What shall i do for that?

Comment: So you need to place the div between if condition, if you want your div on page, and you just don't want to show it than you can simply use `display: none;` in your CSS, but I wouldn't recommend that

Comment: @Alien Sorry, I dont understand, what you are not recommending me.

Comment: @BHARATHYPARTHASARATHY No, why yo need jQuery? you are complicating your stuff

Comment: @BHARATHYPARTHASARATHY Just put your div inside the php condition, that's all I can explain you

Comment: <html><body><?php if(condition>{?><div id='work_exp'></div><?php}?><div id='misc'></div></body></html>. If condition is not true, 'misc' div must come in the place of 'work_exp'. Please help me.

Comment: @BHARATHYPARTHASARATHY You need to replace the word condition with the actual PHP condition, if still you are not able to do it, than I would suggest you to lean PHP

Comment: @Alien if($ename1!=""). This is my condition

Comment: @BHARATHYPARTHASARATHY Ya so what happens when you use that condition

Comment: I must apologize you strongly, because the problem is not with PHP, basically with my designing.. Once again I am very very sorry. Now it's successfully working. I got the output. Thank You so much for spending your valuable time for my request.\

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a "if" before the echo displaying the div :

```
if(...Your_condition...)
{
  echo "<div id='work_exp'> ... </div>";
}
```

PS, you shouldn't build your page using that many echo.

Comment: nor use single quotes in HTML

Comment: @DarkBee It's absolutely fine

Comment: It is better you take out the echo statement

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it server-side, you can do this:

```
<?php
    // ...
    if ($showThisDiv)
    {
        ?>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <?php
    }
    // ...
?>
```

This way you avoid echos, so you don't need to put a lot of HTML in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my new code friends,

```
    <?php
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$obj=$_POST['obj'];
$xdate=$_POST['xdate'];
$xmonth=$_POST['xmonth'];
$xyear=$_POST['xyear'];
$addr=$_POST['addr'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$mob=$_POST['mob'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$ms=$_POST['ms'];


$institute1=$_POST['institute1'];
$qual1=$_POST['qual1'];
$grade1=$_POST['grade1'];
$year1=$_POST['year1'];

$institute2=$_POST['institute2'];
$qual2=$_POST['qual2'];
$grade2=$_POST['grade2'];
$year2=$_POST['year2'];

$institute3=$_POST['institute3'];
$qual3=$_POST['qual3'];
$grade3=$_POST['grade3'];
$year3=$_POST['year3'];

$institute4=$_POST['institute4'];
$qual4=$_POST['qual4'];
$grade4=$_POST['grade4'];
$year4=$_POST['year4'];

$title=$_POST['title'];
$tech=$_POST['tech'];
$domain=$_POST['domain'];
$desc=$_POST['desc'];

$cert=$_POST['cert'];
$intern=$_POST['intern'];

$otrp=$_POST['otrp'];
$csk=$_POST['csk'];
$rwork=$_POST['rwork'];
$salary=$_POST['salary'];

$refname=$_POST['refname'];
$refjob=$_POST['refjob'];
$refadd=$_POST['refadd'];
$refphone=$_POST['refphone'];
$refemail=$_POST['refemail'];
$reflen=$_POST['reflen'];

$ename1=$_POST['ename1'];
$industry1=$_POST['industry1'];
$position1=$_POST['position1'];
$responsibility1=$_POST['responsibility1'];
$from1=$_POST['from1'];
$to1=$_POST['to1'];
$ex1=$_POST['ex1'];

$ename2=$_POST['ename2'];
$industry2=$_POST['industry2'];
$position2=$_POST['position2'];
$responsibility2=$_POST['responsibility2'];
$from2=$_POST['from2'];
$to2=$_POST['to2'];
$ex2=$_POST['ex2'];
?>
<html>
<head>

<title>RESUME</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res.css">
</head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>";
<body>
<center><font size="+3" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">RESUME</font></center><br /><br />
<div id="container">
<div id="pers_detail">
<h3><?php echo $fname; ?></h3>
<h4>ADDRESS</h4>
<p><?php echo $addr; ?><br />
<?php echo $city;?> - <?php echo $pin;?><br />
<?php echo $country;?><br />
</p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="con">
<h4>CONTACT</h4>
<p>
Mobile:<?php echo $mob; ?><br />
E-Mail:<?php echo $email; ?><br />
</p>
</div>
<div id="obj">
<table width="56%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OBJECTIVE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p align="justify"><?php echo $obj; ?></p></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<div id="academy">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   ACADEMIC DETAILS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p align="center"><b>INSTITUTION</b></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><b>QUALIFICATION</b></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><b>CGPA/GRADE</b></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><b>YEAR</b></p></td>
</tr>
<?php 
if(!$institute1!="" || $institute1!="NIL")
{
?>
<tr>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $institute1; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $qual1; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $grade1; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $year1; ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
}
if(!$institute2!="" || $institute2!="NIL")
{?>
<tr>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $institute2; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $qual2; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $grade2; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $year2; ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php 
}
if(!$institute3!="" || $institute3!="NIL")
{?>
<tr>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $institute3; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $qual3; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $grade3; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $year3; ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php 
}
if(!$institute4!="" || $institute4!="NIL")
{?>
<tr>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $institute4; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $qual4; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $grade4; ?></p></td>
<td><p align="center"><?php echo $year4; ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php 
}?>
</table>
</div>
<div id="aca_det">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ACADEMIC PROJECT DETAILS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width><b>TITLE</b></td><td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width><b>TECHNOLOGY USED</b></td><td><?php echo $tech; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=30%><b>DOMAIN</b></td><td><?php echo $domain; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width><b>DESCRIPTION</b></td><td><p align="justify"><?php echo $desc; ?></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php 
if($cert !="NIL" || $intern !="NIL")
{?>
<div id="otherinfo">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OTHER INFORMATIONS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
<?php 
if($cert !="NIL")
{?>
<tr>
<td width><b>CERTIFICATION</b></td><td><?php echo $cert; ?></td></tr>
<tr>
<?php 
}
if($intern !="NIL")
{?>
<td width=30%><b>INTERNSHIP</b></td>
<td><p align="justify"><?php echo $intern; ?></p></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}?>
</table>
</div>
<?php 
}
if($ename1!=""||$ename2!="")
{
?>
<div id="work_exp" style="height:483px">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WORK EXPERIANCE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table width="99%" height="228" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left"><font size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;PROFESSIONAL EXPERIANCE DETAILS</font></td>
</tr>
<?php   
if(!$ename1=="")
{?>
<tr>
<td width="210"><b>Employer</b></td> <td width="327"><?php echo $ename1; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Industry</b></td><td><?php echo $industry1; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Position</b></td><td><?php echo $position1; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Responsibilities</b></td><td><?php echo $responsibility1; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>From</b></td><td><?php echo $from1; ?></td>
<td width="18"><b>To</b></td><td width="249"><?php echo $to1; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="41"><b>Salary</b></td>
<td><?php echo $ex1; ?></td>
</tr>
</table><?php 
}?><BR />

<?php 
if(!$ename2=="")
{?>
<table width="99%" height="179" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td width="210"><b>Employer</b></td> <td width="327"><?php echo $ename2; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Industry</b></td><td><?php echo $industry2; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Position</b></td><td><?php echo $position2; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Responsibilities</b></td><td><?php echo $responsibility2; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>From</b></td><td><?php echo $from2; ?></td>
<td width="18"><b>To</b></td><td width="249"><?php echo $to2; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="23"><b>Salary</b></td>
<td><?php echo $ex2; ?></td>
</tr>

</table><?php
}?>
 </div>
<?php
}?>
<div id="misc" style="height:auto">
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MISCELLANEOUS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%"><b>FULL NAME</b></td>
<td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%"><b>DATE OF BIRTH</b></td>
<td><?php echo $xdate; ?>/<?php echo $xmonth; ?>/<?php echo $xyear; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>GENDER</b></td><td><?php echo $gender; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>MARITAL STATUS</b></td><td width="75%"><?php echo $ms; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>OWN TRANSPORT:</b></td>
<td><?php echo $otrp; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>COMMUNICATION SKILLS:</b></td>
<td><?php echo $csk; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>EXPECTED SALARY:</b></td>
<td><?php echo $salary; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>READY TO WORK:</b></td>
<td><?php echo $rwork; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="ref">
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left"><font style="background-color:#F3F5EF" size="+1" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;REFERENCES&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>NAME</b></td>
<td><?php echo $refname; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>OCCUPATION</b></td>
<td><?php echo $refjob; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>ADDRESS</b></td>
<td><p align="justify"><?php echo $refadd; ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>CONTACT NUMBER</b></td>
<td><?php echo $refphone; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>E-MAIL</b></td>
<td><?php echo $refemail; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>RELATIONSHIP</b></td>
<td><?php echo $reflen; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once again, please indent your code.